# IP SLA on Cisco 1921 IOS 15.2T

Tags: cisco, ip, ios, sla

Can someone explain to me why I cannot create IP SLA probes on a Cisco 1921 with the latest IOS (15.2T). It is clearly available for that IOS on that router model on the [Cisco Feature Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN) ...

```
Router(config)#do sh ver                                                        
Cisco IOS Software, C1900 Software (C1900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(2)T, REL)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport                             
Copyright (c) 1986-2011 by Cisco Systems, Inc.                                  
Compiled Tue 15-Nov-11 20:59 by prod_rel_team                                   

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M9, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)               

Router uptime is 3 days, 18 hours, 32 minutes                                   
System returned to ROM by reload at 15:01:02 UTC Thu Dec 15 2011                
System restarted at 15:02:35 UTC Thu Dec 15 2011                                
System image file is "flash:c1900-universalk9-mz.SPA.152-2.T.bin"               
Last reload type: Normal Reload                                                 
Last reload reason: Reload Command        
...
[snip]                                      

Router(config)#ip sla ?                                                         
  key-chain  Use MD5 Authentication for IP SLAs Control Messages                
  responder  Enable IP SLAs Responder                                           
  server     IPPM server configuration
```

I don't undestand. Any help is welcome,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not very much experience with the 15.x software yet. but to my understanding the "universal" image you are running supports all features, however the available features are limited by the licences activated. Have a look at this link from Cisco aswell http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/modules/ps10598/ordering_guide_c07_557736.html the specific licence "IP SLA" falls under is unknown, but your cisco reseller will be able to answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, the Universal software image has its command set limited by the Feature licences installed. the IP SLA command is available in the "Advanced IP Services feature license". You may check which licences you have available with the command "sh licence"

Comment: Exactly - need to activate _datak9_ feature: `Router(config)#license boot module c1900 technology-package datak9` . Thank you!